# Visual studio c++ схема

Tags: c++, visual-studio, рисование, связи, блок-схема

подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в visual studio такой компонент, с помощью которого можно создавать/рисовать схему во время выполнения программы?

что-то типо этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мы запустили программу. и начали создавать вершины, перетаскивать их и соединять друг с другом. и чтобы потом можно было отследить программно какая вершина с кем имеет связь

Comment: Уточните: а то, что будет нарисовано на экране - соответствует какой структуре данных? мне - навскидку - кажется, что это или дерево, или граф

Comment: граф. нужны связи в любые стороны.

Answer (score 0):

Среди стандартных контролов, там же, где TextBox или DataGrid - я такого не помню. Когда то был ZedGraph, но сейчас даже их домена уже нет. Может, есть какой то сторонний компонент, но навскидку я его не нашел. Возможно, кто то другой подскажет?

На мой взгляд, есть 2 пути:

1. По быстрому написать на коленке свой велосипед, который позволяет мышкой на экране из этих кружочков и линий создать то, что нужно. я несколько раз работал с рисованием и drag-n-drop'ом, там вроде ничего сложного нет. Под рукой сейчас нет готового примера, но если нужно - напишите в комментариях, постараюсь найти или заново придумать.
2. Можно копать в сторону пространства имён `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`. Там всё "по взрослому", эта штука довольно сложная ( вот [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart) на описание базового класса ).

Еще по этой штуке есть [туториал](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd489237(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). К сожалению, этого пространства имён нет в новом .NET, так что работать будет только под виндой. С учетом этого, даже не знаю, стоит л всерёз в этом разбираться.